# Implementing Knuth-Morris-Pratt (KMP) algorithm for string matching with Python

Tags: python, algorithm, string-matching, knuth-morris-pratt

I am following Cormen Leiserson Rivest Stein (clrs) book and came across "kmp algorithm" for string matching. I implemented it using Python (as-is).

However, it doesn't seem to work for some reason. where is my fault?

The code is given below:

```
def kmp_matcher(t,p):
    n=len(t)
    m=len(p)
    # pi=[0]*n;
    pi = compute_prefix_function(p)
    q=-1
    for i in range(n):
        while(q>0 and p[q]!=t[i]):
            q=pi[q]
        if(p[q]==t[i]):
            q=q+1
        if(q==m):
            print "pattern occurs with shift "+str(i-m)
            q=pi[q]


def compute_prefix_function(p):
    m=len(p)
    pi =range(m)
    pi[1]=0
    k=0
    for q in range(2,m):
        while(k>0 and p[k]!=p[q]):
            k=pi[k]
        if(p[k]==p[q]):
            k=k+1
        pi[q]=k
    return pi

t = 'brownfoxlazydog'
p = 'lazy'
kmp_matcher(t,p)
```

Comment: You're trying to read `p[-1]`. That doesn't seem intentional.

Comment: i also triede with p[0]. but no luck..

Comment: @serious_luffy You can see the explanation and resolution of **exactly** what you ask in my answer below. Please accept mine istead. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a class I wrote based on CLRs KMP algorithm, which contains what you are after. Note that only DNA "characters" are accepted here.

```
class KmpMatcher(object):
def __init__(self, pattern, string, stringName):
    self.motif = pattern.upper()
    self.seq = string.upper()
    self.header = stringName
    self.prefix = []
    self.validBases = ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'N']

#Matches the motif pattern against itself.
def computePrefix(self):
    #Initialize prefix array
    self.fillPrefixList()
    k = 0

    for pos in range(1, len(self.motif)):
        #Check valid nt
        if(self.motif[pos] not in self.validBases):
            self.invalidMotif()

        #Unique base in motif
        while(k > 0 and self.motif[k] != self.motif[pos]):
            k = self.prefix[k]
        #repeat in motif
        if(self.motif[k] == self.motif[pos]):
            k += 1

        self.prefix[pos] = k

#Initialize the prefix list and set first element to 0
def fillPrefixList(self):
    self.prefix = [None] * len(self.motif)
    self.prefix[0] = 0

#An implementation of the Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm for linear time string matching
def kmpSearch(self):
    #Compute prefix array
    self.computePrefix()
    #Number of characters matched
    match = 0
    found = False

    for pos in range(0, len(self.seq)):
        #Check valid nt
        if(self.seq[pos] not in self.validBases):
            self.invalidSequence()

        #Next character is not a match
        while(match > 0 and self.motif[match] != self.seq[pos]):
            match = self.prefix[match-1]
        #A character match has been found
        if(self.motif[match] == self.seq[pos]):
            match += 1
        #Motif found
        if(match == len(self.motif)):
            print(self.header)
            print("Match found at position: " + str(pos-match+2) + ':' + str(pos+1))
            found = True
            match = self.prefix[match-1]

    if(found == False):
        print("Sorry '" + self.motif + "'" + " was not found in " + str(self.header))

#An invalid character in the motif message to the user
def invalidMotif(self):
    print("Error: motif contains invalid DNA nucleotides")
    exit()

#An invalid character in the sequence message to the user
def invalidSequence(self):
    print("Error: " + str(self.header) + "sequence contains invalid DNA nucleotides")
    exit()
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation. And, have you tried it? Comparing to the answer of Rohanil, it seems not to work, at least not for me.

Comment: Fixed. I've provided my full class which should aid you in solving the problem. There were a few problems in the original post, mostly with shifting and indexing.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try out my code:

```
def recursive_find_match(i, j, pattern, pattern_track):

    if pattern[i] == pattern[j]:
        pattern_track.append(i+1)
        return {"append":pattern_track, "i": i+1, "j": j+1}
    elif pattern[i] != pattern[j] and i == 0:
        pattern_track.append(i)
        return {"append":pattern_track, "i": i, "j": j+1}

    else:
        i = pattern_track[i-1]
        return recursive_find_match(i, j, pattern, pattern_track)

def kmp(str_, pattern):

    len_str = len(str_)
    len_pattern = len(pattern)
    pattern_track = []

    if len_pattern == 0:
        return
    elif len_pattern == 1:
        pattern_track = [0]
    else:   
        pattern_track = [0]
        i = 0
        j = 1

        while j < len_pattern:
            data = recursive_find_match(i, j, pattern, pattern_track)

            i = data["i"]
            j = data["j"]
            pattern_track = data["append"]

    index_str = 0
    index_pattern = 0
    match_from = -1

    while index_str < len_str:
        if index_pattern == len_pattern:
            break
        if str_[index_str] == pattern[index_pattern]:
            if index_pattern == 0:
                match_from = index_str

            index_pattern += 1
            index_str += 1
        else:
            if index_pattern == 0:
                index_str += 1
            else:
                index_pattern = pattern_track[index_pattern-1]
                match_from = index_str - index_pattern
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def kmp_matcher(t, d):
    n=len(t)
    m=len(d)

    pi = compute_prefix_function(d)
    q = 0
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        if d[q]==t[i]:
            q=q+1
            i = i + 1
        else:
            if q != 0:
                q = pi[q-1]
            else:
                i = i + 1
        if q == m:
            print "pattern occurs with shift "+str(i-q)
            q = pi[q-1]

def compute_prefix_function(p):
    m=len(p)
    pi =range(m)
    k=1
    l = 0
    while k < m:
        if p[k] <= p[l]:
            l = l + 1
            pi[k] = l
            k = k + 1
        else:
            if l != 0:
                l = pi[l-1]
            else:
                pi[k] = 0
                k = k + 1
    return pi

t = 'brownfoxlazydog'
p = 'lazy'
kmp_matcher(t, p)
```

Comment: This has a bug, fails on t = 'aaabc', p = 'aab'

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have fixed it. Now, It outputs `pattern occurs with shift 1` for t = 'aaabc', p = 'aab'.

Comment: This didn't work out for me. pi = range(m)? Why? That leads to an error at pi[k] = l

Comment: @RajeshMappu What are your input values?

Comment: Same text and pattern as in the answer above.

Comment: (and thank you for taking your time and responding to this post) much much appreciated.

Comment: @Rohanil - checked it out? I'm not able to figure out unfortunately.

Comment: pi = range(m) gives a value 0..m. That parsing into pi[k] seems not understandable.

Comment: which python version are you using? It seems to be working with python2.7: check here http://tpcg.io/UJfYDm

Answer (score 1):

KMP stands for *Knuth-Morris-Pratt* it is a linear time string-matching algorithm.

Note that *in python*, the string is **ZERO BASED**, (while *in the book* the string starts with index 1).

So we can workaround this by **inserting an empty space at the beginning** of both strings.

This causes four facts:

1. The `len` of both text and pattern is augmented by 1, so in the *loop range*, we do NOT have  to insert the `+1` to the right interval. (note that in python the last step is excluded);
2. To avoid accesses out of range, you have to check the values of `k+1` and `q+1` BEFORE to give them as index to arrays;
3. Since the length of `m` is augmented by 1, in `kmp_matcher`, before to print the response, you have to check **this** instead: `q==m-1`;
4. For the same reason, to calculate the correct shift you have to compute **this** instead: `i-(m-1)`

so the correct code, **based on your original question**, and considering the starting code from Cormen, as you have requested, would be the following:

(note : I have inserted a matching pattern inside, and some debug text that helped me to find logical errors):

```python
def compute_prefix_function(P):
   m     = len(P)
   pi    = [None] * m
   pi[1] = 0
   k     = 0

   for q in range(2, m):
      print ("q=", q, "\n")
      print ("k=", k, "\n")

      if ((k+1) < m):
         while (k > 0 and P[k+1] != P[q]):
            print ("entered while: \n")
            print ("k: ", k, "\tP[k+1]: ", P[k+1], "\tq: ", q, "\tP[q]: ", P[q])
            k = pi[k]

         if P[k+1] == P[q]:
            k = k+1
            print ("Entered if: \n")
            print ("k: ", k, "\tP[k]: ", P[k], "\tq: ", q, "\tP[q]: ", P[q])
      pi[q] = k
      print ("Outside while or if: \n")
      print ("pi[", q, "] = ", k, "\n")
      print ("---next---")
   print ("---end for---")
   return pi

def kmp_matcher(T, P):
   n  = len(T)
   m  = len(P)
   pi = compute_prefix_function(P)
   q  = 0

   for i in range(1, n):
      print ("i=", i, "\n")
      print ("q=", q, "\n")
      print ("m=", m, "\n")

      if ((q+1) < m):
         while (q > 0 and P[q+1] != T[i]):
            q = pi[q]
         if P[q+1] == T[i]:
            q = q+1
         if q == m-1:
            print ("Pattern occurs with shift", i-(m-1))
            q = pi[q]
      print("---next---")
   print("---end for---")


txt = " bacbababaabcbab"
ptn = " ababaab"
kmp_matcher(txt, ptn)
```

(so this would be the correct accepted answer...)

hope that it helps.